# Creating symbolic links in a for loop

Tags: bash, shell-script

With a single argument, `ln -s` will create a symlink in the current directory:

```
$ ls /opt/my_tests
hello_world.c hello_world
$ 
$ echo $PWD
/home/chris/my_links
$ ln -s /opt/my_tests/hello_world.c
$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 chris chris 28 May  3 13:08 hello_world.c -> /opt/my_tests/hello_world.c
```

but, if I try doing this in a for loop, it reckons the file exists:

```
$ for f in "/opt/my_tests/*"
> do
> ln -s $f
> done
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/opt/my_tests/hello_world.c': File exists
```

What am I misunderstanding / doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're quoting the glob, which results in it not being expanded at for loop evaluation time. Later you have a bare, unquoted `$f`, which expands the previously quoted glob and results in all of the files matching the glob being passed at once to `ln`.

Compare:

```
$ touch foo bar baz
$ for file in "*"; do echo ln -s $file; done
ln -s bar baz foo
$ for file in *; do echo ln -s "$file"; done
ln -s bar
ln -s baz
ln -s foo
```

So what you really want is to expand the glob at for loop evaluation time, and then quote the resulting item (with or without quotes for `/opt/my_tests/`):

```
for file in /opt/my_tests/*; do
    ln -s "$file"
done
```

Comment: Ah, those pesky quotation marks again... thanks!